# Rewriting python arrays manipulation function in haskell

Tags: python, haskell

So I wanted to try to rewrite my pivot routine in haskell, but I got stuck right away...

Here is my original python routine (i've commented it heavily to compensate for the lack of types):

```
def pivot(entering, leaving, B, A, Z):
    """
    @param entering integer indicating the entering col #
    @param leaving integer indicating the leaving col #
    @param B vector/array of integers, representing the basis
    @param A matrix of floating point numbers
    @param Z vector/array of floating point numbers
    returns tuple:
        (B, A, Z) with pivoted tableau
    """

    # Copy A
    M = [row for row in A]
    # Append Z row to the matrix
    M.append(Z)

    # Find the main row
    eq_no = B.index(leaving)
    col = entering

    # Go through all other rows and do Gaussian elimination on them:
    for i in range(len(M)):
        if i == eq_no:
            continue
        # Do pivot - ignore "zero_out" function for now
        #            assume it returns a vector same size as row M[i]
        M[i] = zero_out(M[i], M[eq_no], col)

    # Reassign B's
    Bprime = [b for b in B]  # copy B
    Bprime[eq_no] = entering  # replace

    # return new B, matrix M (less 1 row), and last row of M
    return (Bprime, M[:len(M)-1], M[len(M)-1])
```

Here is how far I got...

```
type Matrix = [ [Double] ]
type Vector = [ [Vector] ]

matrix = [ [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
hello:: Matrix -> Int
hello m = length m

pivot:: Int -> Int -> Vector -> Matrix -> Matrix -> Matrix
pivot entering leaving b a z = 
    let m = a::z
        eq_no = elemIndex leaving b
        case eq_no of
            Just no -> no
            Nothing -> 1
        col = entering

    in  ????
```

I am very interested in how people might implement the "matrix" and "vector" types, and also how they will manipulate the arrays - like replacing elements in them or rows in a matrix.

Let me know if something is not clear, and thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `Vector` type is correct?

Comment: http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/haskell/haskell-intro-html/arrays.html#sect11.5 this might be helpful

Comment: Lol - not it's not. I just gave up compiling at that point :-(

Comment: @dmitry.malikov wow that look cryptic. So. many. symbols...

Comment: @drozzy symbols I see: list comprehension syntax `[ foo | x <- gen, baz]`, tuple syntax `(foo, bar)`, array indexing `arr ! index`, guard syntax `| predicate = expression`. These are all fairly basic Haskell; perhaps give earlier sections of the tutorial a read, or start with [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com)

Comment: Thanks, I've read 7 chapters of LYAH - the problem is not with the syntax, but with writing it for the first time. I don't even know how to approach it. Remember the 1st time you had to write a prog in new language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to take the time right now to translate your code into Haskell, but I am going to critique the code you have and offer a few tips.

First of all, the type `[Foo]` means "list of Foo". And by "list" I mean immutable, singly-linked list. The `Matrix` type makes perfect sense: a Matrix is a list of "rows", where a "row" is a list of Double. However, your `Vector` type makes no sense. Perhaps you meant to say:

```
type Vector = [Double]
type Matrix = [Vector]
```

Back to lists in general. Lists can be indexed with the `!!` operator. For example

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"] !! 1 == "bar"
```

You can *prepend* an element with `:` (pronounced "cons")

```
"quux" : ["foo", "bar", "baz"] == ["quux", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

You can append two lists with `++`

```
[1,2] ++ [3,4] == [1,2,3,4]
```

You can therefore append an element with `list ++ [x]`, although this is inefficient and not recommended. In fact, indexing is rather slow as well. If you need efficient indexing and appending, use [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) instead. But as a beginner I wouldn't recommend you worry much about efficiency for now.

---

I'd suggest you learn a little more Haskell before trying to translate code; your Python algorithm makes use of mutation, which is generally avoided in Haskell, though certainly possible. Once you get a little more experience with Haskell types and functions, then you may be interested in the [vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! What about replacing an element at a given index in an array?

Comment: @drozzy If you start replacing the elements at particular indices in a _list_ (not array! there's a difference), you will almost certainly regret it soon after.

Comment: @drozzy If you *really* want to do stuff like that, check out [Data.Sequence # indexing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#g:11). `Seq` is a purely functional data structure, which still retains pretty good performance when doing stuff like that. If you want the raw performance of mutable arrays, then [use those](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.3.0.3/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html). Not recommended until you have at *least* read through LYAH, and probably RWH too.